# Filter rows by matching partial strings from a list to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with a "description" column. I would like to extract all those rows from this dataframe by identifying partial matches from a list(mylist).

```
df
------------------
id   description
 111    abcxyz
 212    ab10yz
 203    abcdd9
 442    ab00-z
 554    a12x0z
 697    a9901z


mylist: ['ab','yz']
```

There are similar questions but mostly focus on either full matching of the list items to dataframe column.

I am interested in matching items from mylist with the description column of the dataframe and return those rows as a dataframe where a match is found.

Expected result as a dataframe:

```
------------------
id   description
111    abcxyz
212    ab10yz
203    abcdd9
442    ab00-z
```

I have tried different solutions. Here I will mention two of these as the following:

```
df[df.description.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))]

df[df['description'].str.contains(mylist)]
```

The first line above resulted in:

```
   KeyError: '[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] not in index'
```

The second line to code results in:

```
   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Although in your case I think you may also want to add `na=False`: `df[df.description.str.contains('|'.join(mylist), na=False)]`

Comment: I get an empty dataframe, which is not correct. I should get output with rows id  111, 212, 203, 442, as the df['descrption'] matches with ab and yz items from the list.

Comment: `df[df.description.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))]` works well for me (pandas 0.24.2).

Comment: Sorry, but we can't reproduce your error.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake with a variable. It works with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, "DataFrame.str.contains" already can do that:

```
pt = '.*?({}).*?'.format('|'.join(mlist))
df[df['description'].str.contains(pt, regex= True)]
```